# Changing field labels affect email merge templates?

Tags: email-template, fields

When changing field labels in Salesforce, it will complain about how doing so might break merge templates. Our email templates use the API name of the field, not the label. Will changing the label of a field affect the email templates at all? What about Mail Merge templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing labels only effects templates that **display** a label, and so shouldn't break anything, just effect the output.  I've seen label changes impact Visualforce pages and reports more often than email templates.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. However, the warning message makes is sound like the Label change will break merge templates.

Comment: Mail Merge templates use labels, not API names. Not that anyone uses Mail Merge...